# How to call dynamic method in widget - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, sharedpreferences

I'm new to flutter.
I'm using SharedPreferences to store data.
I have this dynamic function :

```
 _loadFromLocal(index) async {
    var data = await getFromLocal();
    return data?.elementAt(index);
  }

 Future<List<String>?> getFromLocal() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getStringList('data_prices');
  }
```

I need to call this dynamic fucntion _loadFromLocal in Widget build

```dart
    class _ScanState extends State<Scan> {
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return
     Scaffold(
         child: Container(
        child:Text(
        _loadFromLocal(0),
        )),);
  }
  }
```

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't call async code as you mentioned, instead you should call it in `initState()` like below

```dart
class _ScanState extends State<Scan> {
  dynamic value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadFromLocal(0).then((data) {
      setState(() {
        value = data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(
          value ?? '',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // omit the rest code
}
```